# $http not defined when posting to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

Here's my json:

```
[
    {
        "name": "AAAAAA",
        "date": "28-03-2016",
    },
    {
        "name": "BBBBBB",
        "date": "20-12-2016",
    },
    {
        "name": "CCCCCC",
        "date": "09-01-2016",
    },
    {
        "name": "DDDDDD",
        "date": "21-07-2016",
    }
]
```

My javascript:

```
   var app = angular.module('app', []);
   app.service('service', function($http, $q){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('names.json').then(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });

        this.getNames = function() {
            return deferred.promise;
        }

    });
    app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service) {
        var promise = service.getNames();
        promise.then(function (data) {
                $scope.names = data.data;
                console.log($scope.names);

            }
        );
        $scope.postfunction = function() {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'serverUrl',
                data: name.name,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            })
        };

    });
```

My HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
        <td>{{name.name}}</td>
        <td>{{name.time | date}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="postfunction()">POST</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What I want do is when I click the button "POST" name.name post to server. I try `$http.post` in `postfunction()`, but I get "$http is not defined" in console.

Comment: Why don't you just do the post within the service? Then you don't even need to inject $http into your controller, like the answers already state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to inject $http into your controller

```
app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service, $http) {
                                                      ^
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to inject $http service in your controller 'FirstCtrl' as below:

```
app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service, $http) {
    var promise = service.getNames();
    promise.then(function (data) {
            $scope.names = data.data;
            console.log($scope.names);

        }
    );
    $scope.postfunction = function(name) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'serverUrl',
            data: name,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        })
    };

});
```

Also additionally along with passing the argument to the post function, you have to pass the 'name' in the HTML as below, this is because, in your controller, 'name' is never defined.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
        <td>{{name.name}}</td>
        <td>{{name.time | date}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="postfunction(name.name)">POST</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```